# how to apply an impulse to an entire catagorybitmask in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a game that is constantly spawning lots of birds that move along the screen. They are effected by gravity so every half a second i want to apply an impulse to the birds to create a flapping effect. The problem is I can only apply an impulse to the last bird spawned. How can I apply an impulse to the entire category bit mask?

Comment: Sounds like you assign each new bird to the same variable (ivar) thus replacing the previous references. You need to use an array or use Sprite Kit's enumerate.. function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply how would I go about using an array

Comment: Keep birds in array and apply impulse to each of them.

Comment: use SkAction runBlock every second and enumerate thru nodes. check if the node's categoryBitMask is bird category, if it is then apply impulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andy has pointed out, you should store the birds in an array.

METHOD A
Create a sequence of actions that will repeat forever.  The sequence should simply be:

1. Wait for .5 seconds (`SKAction`)
2. Loop through the array and apply an impulse to every item (`SKAction` requiring `runBlock:`)

`runBlock:` is a "custom" `SKAction` that allows you to trigger code synchronously with the sequence.

METHOD B
Create an `NSTimeInterval* timeSinceLastImpulse`

```
Update:(NSTimeInterval*)timeSinceLast
{
    timeSinceLastImpulse+=timeSinceLast;
    if(timeSinceLastImpulse >= .5)//check if it has been half a second
    {
        //run through array and apply impulse
        timeSinceLastImpulse = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope these options send you in the right direction!